# When a python script is executed inside a python script, I do not get the complete output

Tags: python, file, subprocess, shfileoperation

When a python script is executed inside a python script, I do not get the complete output. In my case:

```
os.system('python -u capture.py > capture.log &')
```

where capture.py will capture the packets and feeds this to capture.log.

Capture.py will keep sending packets every 100 sec. I couldn't see the complete output in to the file. Only the initial captures are put to capture.log because capture.py doesn't capture any packets after some time.

However, when I execute the same script via "python -u" in the bash prompt, it works.

Comment: does your script flush the output when printing?

Comment: why run a Python script from Python like that anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a `subprocess` with `io.system(...)`.
Read the docs: [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)

You have use [module-subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)